# UITableViewCell: unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I've got a `UITableViewCell` that I'm creating, and I am using auto layout with constraints constructed entirely in code.

While the actual output in the app is fine (i.e., it looks just as I have designed it to look), I am getting the famous "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" error/warning message.

Here is the list of constraints printed by the error message:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb2f280e5e0 V:|-(0)-[UIScrollView:0x7fb2f0435730]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fb2f04345c0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb2f280e880 V:[UIScrollView:0x7fb2f0435730(280)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb2f280e630 V:[UIScrollView:0x7fb2f0435730]-(16)-[UIScrollView:0x7fb2f04360d0]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb2f280e920 V:[UIScrollView:0x7fb2f04360d0(140)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb2f280e970 V:[UIScrollView:0x7fb2f04360d0]-(16)-[SummaryView:0x7fb2f0436c20]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb2f280e9f0 V:[SummaryView:0x7fb2f0436c20(140)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb2f280e8d0 V:[SummaryView:0x7fb2f0436c20]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fb2f04345c0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb2f0439e30 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fb2f04345c0(44)]>"
```

Every single one of them is completely correct and exactly what I wanted except for the last one. That one is quite clearly system generated. 44 points is (I believe) the system-standard cell height. What's curious to me is that I have explicitly stated a correct cell height (in this case, 592 points). Here is what I have done in my `UITableViewController` subclass:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [TableViewCell heightNeededForCell];
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [TableViewCell heightNeededForCell];
}
```

I think the reason this is happening is because of my cell's `init` function:

```
#pragma mark - Table View Cell Lifecycle
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self != nil) {
        [self setupUserInterface];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - UI Setup
- (void)setupUserInterface {
    [self createControls];
    [self createConstants];
    [self setupControls];
    [self layoutControls];
    [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded]; <-- Here's where the warning occurs
    // The UIScrollViews (which contain UIImageViews) were not
    // adjusting their contentSize properly, so I do it manually here
    self.scrollView1.contentSize = self.heartImageView1.bounds.size;
    self.scrollView2.contentSize = self.heartImageView2.bounds.size;
    }
}
```

From my results, it appears that I can safely ignore this error, but I'm kinda picky and don't like the fact that I'm getting a warning, even if I can explain it and it doesn't appear to cause any trouble. How would I successfully change the system-supplied constraint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that the unexpected constraint is coming from the `UITableView` machinery itself.

I think when you call `layoutIfNeeded` in the initializer, you are confusing the `UITableView` machinery which expects to be responsible for doing layout on the cell as a whole, and for ensuring that the cell wraps its own `contentView` correctly. So you've told `contentView` to layout, but the cell itself has not been told to layout in tandem at the right time. What is the right time? Only `UITableView` knows its own secrets...

There's probably more than one way to workaround the problem but what I'd suggest is to switch to using self-sizing cells. That way you'd be taking responsibility for exactly what `UITableView` expects you to handle, leaving less room for surprises. Since you're already defining the cell's layout with Auto Layout, you're almost there already.

Here's how to do it:

1. Just add another layout constraint to the content view constraining it to your desired height of 592 points.
2. Then remove the delegate methods for `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` and `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` entirely.
3. Then set `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 600` (or any value, actually) in `viewDidLoad`.

Now the tableView will set the cells to the height 592, which is the height that the cells themselves declare that they prefer via their own Auto Layout constraints.

There are some examples of numerous ways to do this here: https://github.com/algal/TableViewSpike.

Note: Self-sizing cells requires a deployment target of iOS 8.0 or above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does not make sense to me to circumvent the provided protocol methods in order to encapsulate the height sizing inside of the cell itself, when to do so requires me to put in a fake value for `estimatedRowHeight`. Instead, because my problem was related to `UIScrollView` and `UIImageView` sizing and content sizing, I moved that code into another method which I call after I get my cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Not the most elegant, I admit, but it now works properly and my login is still (IMHO) divided as it needs to be.

Comment: I am not suggesting you "circumvent" anything or use fake values! What I'm suggesting is the official, documented way to use the API. Namely, if your cell defines sufficient Auto Layout constraints to define its own height, then setting `estimatedRowHeight` to _any non-zero value_ is how you tell `UITableView` that you want it to use Auto Layout to calculate the cell's height. This is explained in WWDC 2014, "What's New in Table And Collection Views".

Comment: In fact, in that talk, the entire reason Apple gives for introducing the self-sizing machinery is to save people from doing the manual sizing that you describe in your comment (if I'm understanding you right). Ironic!

Comment: I'll take a look at that video, but it seems odd to me that *any non-zero value* has the same effect on layout. My cell heights change per device, so it seems misleading to me to set a single, static value to indicate auto-sizing. If, instead, I set that value using my calculations, then I've effectively just moved the exact same code from the protocol method to, say, `viewDidLoad`. By the way, even when I tried your approach exactly, I still had the same issue, because the separator still causes weird 0.5 point issues. Turning off the separator fixed that, but that's not what I want.

Comment: Again, I'll look at the video, but moving my explicit layout code to another method which I call from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` solves my issue and doesn't introduce the oddities I mentioned in my previous comment. I'm not arguing with your assertion that Apple has made this the "correct" way; I'm arguing that until there's a boolean value like `tableView.cellsUseAutolayout = YES;`, sticking with the old methods make more sense to me. Thanks for giving me something to learn, though! ;-)

Comment: I agree it's odd but frankly it's an odd API. I could have said to set the estimated row height to 592 but that would have obscured that the estimate is acting both as an estimate and crucially _as a flag_ to enable self-sizing, and that the exact figure comes from the layout constraints. If you're seeing an separator-sized layout error, my first guess would be that you have inadvertently installed the height constraint on the cell itself, when it should be installed on the contentView. But hard to say without seeing more. Good luck.

Comment: FWIW, you can also set rowHeight = UIViewAutomaticDimension, which makes your intention more explicit in the code.

Comment: And if you have found my answer acceptable in some respect, please consider accepting it. ;)

Comment: I simply cannot get your method to work. `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` appears to only be valid for headers and footers. I have upvoted and accepted your answer, because it has given me very valuable information, but I don't really think it "solved" my issue. That may change after I watch the video you referenced.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82230/discussion-between-mbm29414-and-algal).

Comment: Hmm. Well, I use this API regularly and the repo provides seven distinct examples of it, so I feel pretty confident. If you have an isolated sample you can share, I'd be glad to look, as I have a weird passion for Auto Layout. But if what you've got is working, then ¯\_(ツ)_/¯